# Cannot Resolve Overloaded Method IntelliJ 2018.2.8 / Scala 2.11.8/Spark 2.4.5

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

IntelliJ was working fine a couple of days earlier. Today it gave me strange error

Cannot resolve overloaded method.

[image]

Can somebody help me in solving this error?

Comment: Does it work? `spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("your_path")` You can try to copy project, remove `.idea` directory and then import it to intellij.

Comment: I tried coping removing .idea . But error persists

Answer (score 0):

Try File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.. | **Invalidate and Restart** and open project via File | New | project from Existing Sources action and select pom.xml file to import from.

Comment: I Created new project from existing sources. But error persists.